# iOS integration with Heroku backend

Tags: ios, ruby, heroku, applepay

I have been having a lot of difficulty with this, I just can't see where I am going wrong. Although I am fairly rookie, I am trying to do something a ton of app developers must routinely succeed in doing - process an Apple Pay charge through Stripe's example Sinatra / Ruby backend available at:

https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend

I believe I have done everything fine:

My Stripe account is set up, I am in test mode, I have verified my bank, it all looks fine.

I am using Test API keys, secret and publishable : the following is the code in my slightly modified web.ry file: you can see that the app working at least at the ‘/‘ endpoint if you go to: https://ibidurubypay.herokuapp.com - please note I have absolutely NO IDEA what I am doing in Rails - the only mods I have made are:

I have inserted the Stripe test key
I have slightly modified the initial return message to check changes are being updated on Heroku
I changed the currency to GBP (stripe account is GBP)

Code is:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'stripe'
require 'dotenv'
require 'json'

Dotenv.load

Stripe.api_key = ENV['sk_test_mystripetestkeymystripetestkey']

get '/' do
    status 200
    return "Great, terrific, your backend is set up. Now you can configure the Stripe example iOS apps to point here."
end

post '/charge' do

    # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    source = params[:source] || params[:stripe_token] || params[:stripeToken]
    customer = params[:customer]

    # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    begin
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                                       :amount => params[:amount], # this number should be in cents
                                       :currency => "gbp",
                                       :customer => customer,
                                       :source => source,
                                       :description => "Example Charge"
                                       )
                                       rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
                                       status 402
                                       return "Error creating charge: #{e.message}"
    end

    status 200
    return "Charge successfully created"

end

get '/customers/:customer/cards' do

    customer = params[:customer]

    begin
        # Retrieves the customer's cards
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer)
        rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
        status 402
        return "Error retrieving cards: #{e.message}"
    end

    status 200
    content_type :json
    cards = customer.sources.all(:object => "card")
    selected_card = cards.find {|c| c.id == customer.default_source}
    return { :cards => cards.data, selected_card: selected_card }.to_json

end

post '/customers/:customer/sources' do

    source = params[:source]
    customer = params[:customer]

    # Adds the token to the customer's sources
    begin
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer)
        customer.sources.create({:source => source})
        rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
        status 402
        return "Error adding token to customer: #{e.message}"
    end

    status 200
    return "Successfully added source."

end

post '/customers/:customer/select_source' do

    source = params[:source]
    customer = params[:customer]

    # Sets the customer's default source
    begin
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer)
        customer.default_source = source
        customer.save
        rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
        status 402
        return "Error selecting default source: #{e.message}"
    end

    status 200
    return "Successfully selected default source."

end

delete '/customers/:customer/cards/:card' do

    card = params[:card]
    customer = params[:customer]

    # Deletes the source from the customer
    begin
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer)
        customer.sources.retrieve(card).delete()
        rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
        status 402
        return "Error deleting card"
    end

    status 200
    return "Successfully deleted card."

end
```

As you can see the Ruby web app is running fine…

Switching to Xcode, I then go and download Stripe's example apps at:    https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example

I open ‘Stripe.xcworkspace’ in the ‘stripe-ios-master’ folder.

In my Apple Developer account, I go set up a new app ‘com.AH.thenameigaveit’ Merchant

I ticked ApplePay and then set up a Merchant Identifier with: merchant.com.AH.thenameigaveit

I go to Stripe and create a CSR certificate which I then link up with my Merchant ID in Apple Dev.

I got my new Apple CER file and uploaded it to Stripe - and I was able to verify that it was successfully installed.

Back in Xcode I hit Fix Issue for provisioning profile problem and it all gets accepted.

My entitlements file says ‘com.apple.developer.in-app-payments’

Now in Xcode I go to ViewController.swift in Stripe's 'Simple' example and change the values of the various user variables as follows:

stripePublishableKey = “'pk_test_mystripetestkeymystripetestkey'” my test publishable key

backendChargeURLString = “https://ibidurubypay.herokuapp.com”

appleMerchantId = “merchant.com.AH.thenameigaveit”

Note the Stripe 'Simple' example Swift code refers to currency as USD whereas my web.ry script refers to “gbp”, however from what I can tell in the past when I tried it a couple of times each way, that looks as if it shouldn’t matter as the currency value is not passed to the Ruby script (and my Stripe account is in GBP.)

So, time to build and run to an iPhone 6 plus with Apple Pay activated on it with a live Visa credit card… app builds successfully first time..

First time around it says :”Payment request is invalid: check your entitlements”, so I go to Capabilities and make sure the correct Merchant ID is checked against ApplePay - build again and this time we get further - the Apple Pay screen comes up perfectly on the screen, specifying the Apple Pay linked credit card to pay $10 for the cool shirt.. - I do the touch, it comes up with ‘Processing Payment’ then shortly after ‘Payment Not Completed!’ and the Apple Pay dialog retreats back down the screen taking back to the option to ‘Buy a shirt’

So, I know absolutely nothing about communicating with this server backend except to try and glean some info coming back from the call, so I insert:

```
print ("data: \(data), \r\r response: \(response), \r\r error: \(error)")
```

which gives me:

> data: Optional(),
>
> response: Optional( { URL:
>   *(ASBEFORE)*ibidurubypay.herokuapp.com/charge } { status code: 402, headers {
>       Connection = "keep-alive";
>       "Content-Length" = 248;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Tue, 28 Jun 2016 00:16:43 GMT";
>       Server = "WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.2/2014-05-08)";
>       Via = "1.1 vegur";
>       "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
>       "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
>       "X-Xss-Protection" = "1; mode=block"; } }),
>
> error: nil

That appears to be a Card Decline message, but there’s nothing wrong with the card.

On my Stripe account at the portal,  a token was successfully created at the time: 2016/06/28 01:16:42

…however, there is no evidence of the 402 decline I can see anywhere here, maybe I am not looking in the right place…

I would be really grateful if anyone could let me know what’s going wrong - I am tearing my hair out, I have been stumped on this on and off for days.

Comment: Since you're new to Ruby, I recommend reading a bit about `byebug` and using it to do some debugging. You'll can place a breakpoint in your controller action and make sure that the correct parameters are being sent from the client. Also make sure to test your `Stripe::Charge.create` call in `irb` before trying to connect it to the front-end. It helps to test pieces of code in isolation to identify the true culprit of errors.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I had asked the guys from Stripe this question and blow me over they solved it straight off - the issue was:

Stripe.api_key = ENV['sk_test_mystripetestkeymystripetestkey'] in my Ruby script...

EITHER: it should be:

Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_mystripetestkeymystripetestkey' (note no ENV[])

OR: BETTER: if should be as it was originally downloaded from Stripe, an environment variable, which I then set up in Stripe, so in the script:

Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY']

then update your Heroku configuration to create an environment variable named `STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY` with your test API key as the value: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Easy as pie once you know how, thank you Stripe for great support!